# Where to store small data for a project (React, Next.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, file, next.js

I'm building a personal portfolio in Next.JS. I have a small section that showcases multiple projects. Each project has its own data such as image, title, links and etc. I want to store data of these projects, but I'm not sure where to store such a small data.

Is it a good idea to store such data locally as a json file?
Is it better to store it as a Next.JS API?

What is the best and easiest option to store such data without configuring a server?

P.S I don't want to store such small data on a server or configure a local storage.

Comment: Maybe json file is perfect,or you can store and export it in a js file in order to facilitate management.

Answer (score 1):

I think google firebase a very simple and powerful tool to save you data.

And is it for free under certain amount of use.

Here is a simple and complete app using Firebase to persist data:  https://github.com/walterfcarvalho/habits-monitor